# function doesn't implemented since onload()

Tags: javascript, jsp, onload

I am using `jsp` to render some data and making a test by using the following codes:

```
<html>
    <head>
           <title>D3 Demo</title>
    </head>

    <script language="javascript">

    function access(){
        alert("entered");
        var outputjson = "<%=responseJson%>";
        alert(outputjson);
    }
    </script>

    <body onload = "access()">         
           <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
           <p><%=responseJson%></p>
    </body>




</html>
```

From the browser I can tell that the `body` contains the `<h1>` and `<p>` content as `This is a Heading` and a `Java` variable, `responseJson`. But I didn't get any alert pop up. It seems that the `access` function never get called. But in the `body`, I do call it so that when the page get loaded, it should pop up 2 alerts.

What's the issue here?

Comment: [Not sure, but your code works in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k0hou284/1/).

Comment: This is really weird... Since I can inspect the `var outputjson` did get the value of the `responseJson` by using the `inspect element` of Chrome. But the function access never get called...

Comment: There shouldn’t be any tags between or around `head` and `body`. So far your HTML is invalid.

Comment: @byteBiter, just move your script block inside `<head>` like Xufox suggests. I missed that, which is why my jsfiddle works.

Answer (score 0):

I just find out the problem.

Since the `responseJson` in `Java` returns a `JSON` String contains `""`, thus the `outputjson` variable actually has syntax error, which results in that `access()` method didn't get compiled. That's why in `onload`, the browser can not find an method called `access`.

By making such an edition (Using single quote):

```
var outputjson = '<%=responseJson%>';
```

It works well. FYI